# ASP.Net MVC Authentication with a custom service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am starting a new MVC project for one of my clients. They already have an iPhone app which is having most of the functionalities that I intend to do. And a web service exists. I do not have any database side work. My question is, I want to use the web service calls for authentication. But asp.net MVC is using Identity as default authentication. How do I tackle to use Identity with out much effort to call the web service for authentication?

Comment: Interesting question. I guess you should start with a custom storage provider, but I am not sure how that works with the password as it mentions hashes. See http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity.

Comment: Thanks Niels. I will try